# How to get bootstrap tab's content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a search bar for FAQ page that I'm doing with bootstrap's tabs. When clicking on the buttons the tab's content appears - but when searching the content it does not appear. I've tried to get the content by matching the div's id and then setting the div's display from `none` to `inline-block` (to make it visible) but it caused other problems....

```
  $('#faq_search').on('keyup', function() {

    var filter = $(this).val();
    if (filter.length > 2) {

      $(".faq_cont_right ul li").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('foo');
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
          $(this).show();

        } else {

          $(this).show();
          $(this).addClass('foo');

        }
      });

    } else {
      $(".faq_cont_right ul li").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('foo');
      });
    }

  });
```

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N3awMbbLbwadH5XSlsNS?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

change your srcipt.js .... it will work :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#faq_search').on('keyup',function(){

           var filter = $(this).val();
           if (filter.length > 2) {

           // Loop through the comment list
           $(".faq_cont_right ul li").each(function(){
               $(this).removeClass('foo');
               // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
               if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                   //$(this).fadeOut();
                   $(this).show();
                   // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
               } else {

                   $(this).show();
                   $(this).addClass('foo');

               }
           });
            $(".tab-content>.active").each(function(){
               $(this).removeClass('foo');
               // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
               if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                   //$(this).fadeOut();
                   $(this).show();
                   // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
               } else {

                   $(this).show();
                   $(this).addClass('foo');

               }
           });


} else{
   $(".faq_cont_right ul li").each(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('foo');
   });
    $(".tab-content>.active").each(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('foo');
   });
}


       });
    });
```

Comment: Minar - thanks for the quick answer, unfortunately it's not working, i want to view the tab's content from when searching in the same way like clicking on the tabs....

Answer (score 0):

Got it.... simply needed to trigger the click event when match results found....
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#faq_search').on('keyup', function() {

```
   var filter = $(this).val();
   if (filter.length > 2) {

     // Loop through the comment list
     $(".faq_cont_right ul li").each(function() {
       $(this).removeClass('foo');
       // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
       if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
         //$(this).fadeOut();
         $(this).show();
         // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
       } else {

         $(this).show();
         $(this).addClass('foo').trigger('click'); 

       }
     });
     $(".tab-content>.active").each(function() {
       $(this).removeClass('foo');
       // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
       if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
         //$(this).fadeOut();
         $(this).show();
         // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
       } else {

         $(this).show();
         $(this).addClass('foo');

       }
     });


   } else {
     $(".faq_cont_right ul li").each(function() {
       $(this).removeClass('foo');
     });
     $(".tab-content>.active").each(function() {
       $(this).removeClass('foo');
     });
   }


 });
```

});